# Elasticsearch Nest 6.5.1. How do I get the Raw Request being sent to Elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using Elasticsearch 6.5.1 and would like to see the raw request being sent to Elasticsearch. I have set DisableDirectStreaming on my ConnectionSettings, but after making a GetAsync call the IGetResponse.ApiCall.RequestBodyInBytes is always null. However, the ResponseBodyInbytes is fine.

Please can someone explain how I can see the RequestBodyInBytes when using Elasticsearch Nest 6.5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the request being sent to elasticsearch in `DebugInformation` of every response object once `DisableDirectStreaming` is enabled. [Link to NEST documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/6.x/debug-information.html).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Rob thanks for the quick reply. I have tried your suggestion but 
DebugInformation still shows: # Request:
<Request stream not captured or already read to completion by serializer. Set DisableDirectStreaming() on ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.>  I have confirmed that DisableDirectStreaming is set to true prior to the request being sent to Elasticsearch. Response information is shown as expected.

Comment: I think that may be correct behaviour if there is no actual request body in your request, [have a look](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/src/Elasticsearch.Net/Responses/ResponseStatics.cs#L31). Could you share the NEST call you are trying to audit?

Comment: Code Snippet of Nest Call
 var response = await _client.Connection.GetAsync(
     DocumentPath<Types.TsAdmin>.Id(objectName),
     descriptor => descriptor
      .Index(AdminIndexName()));

Comment: Contents of DebugInformation

Valid NEST response built from a successful low level call on GET: /tsadmins/tsadmin/TsObjectData
# Audit trail of this API call:
 - [1] HealthyResponse: Node: XXXXX Took: 00:00:00.0430021
# Request:
<Request stream not captured or already read to completion by serializer. Set DisableDirectStreaming() on ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.>
# Response:
{"_index":"tsadmins","_type":"tsadmin","_id":"TsObjectData","_version":447,"found":true,"_source":{"objectName":"TsObjectData","indexType":"MonthIndex"}}

Comment: That makes sense as retrieving document from elasticsearch is just GET request with no body in the request: `GET: /tsadmins/tsadmin/TsObjectData`

Comment: I understand now. When trying a query with filtering I see the  RequestBodyInBytes set. You have answered my question perfectly. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I believe you also have to call [EnableDebugMode()](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/6.x/configuration-options.html) on your connection settings.

Another option would be to call

```
var jsonString = yourclient.RequestResponseSerializer.SerializeToString(yourdescriptor);
```

on your descriptor, but debugMode is alot more convenient in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try this.